# Roblox Python Buy Item with post requests

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, roblox

I am trying to buy an item with the roblox api in python. However I am having trouble finding the link to make a post request to purchase an item. Here is my code so far:

```
def buyItem(self,itemid, cookie):
    info = self.getItemInfo(itemid)
    url="https://api.roblox.com/item.ashx?rqtype=purchase&productID={}&expectedCurrency=1&expectedPrice={}&expectedSellerID={}&userAssetID=".format(info["ProductId"], 0 if info["PriceInRobux"] == None else info["PriceInRobux"],info["Creator"]["Id"])
    print(url)
    cookies = {
        '.ROBLOSECURITY': cookie
    }
    headers = {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': self.setXsrfToken(cookie)
    }
    r = self.s.post(url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
    return r
```

I get 400 errors and the error code is {"errors":[{"code":400,"message":"BadRequest"}]}
I just need to figure out the correct url to send the post request to. Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using selenium!

the reason for this is because it is much simpler!

Example code for buying an item with selenium:

```
from time import sleep as wait
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 

driver.get("https://www.roblox.com/catalog/139152472/Holiday-Crown") ##opens the link

wait(30) ## gives you 30 seconds to sign in before the script runs!

driver.find_element_by_class("btn-fixed-width-lg btn-growth-lg PurchaseButton").click()## clicks the element it finds with that class
driver.find_element_by_id("confirm-btn").click() ##clciks the the comfirm button
```

If you need a little bit of help heres meh discord: Encryptal#3233

Heres my roblox account: Encryptal

Im learning this to so i could help you out and explain it!
:D

### Also if your bored and have no one to play roblox .........

Comment: I added you on discord. I just have some questions